# Question on Pine-script: Executing multiple alternative rows of code

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to find out if there is a way to run several rows of code while preventing other several rows from running in pine-script. Hope the following sample code scenario clarifies my intentions:

```
//@version=4
study("Example Code", overlay = true, shorttitle = "ExampleCode")

//I have created an drop down selector input:
DropDownInput = input(title="Select Input”, defval="Green", options=["Green", "Yellow", "Red"])

// Is there a way for me to select multiple rows of the below code to run based on whichever color is selected at the above DropDownInput 

// "Green" Code would be something like and if "Green" is selected at DropDownInput only these rows of code would execute
ShortMA = input(defval=15)
LongMA = input(defval=30)
ShortMACode = sma(close,ShortMA)
LongMACode = sma(close,LongMA)
BUYSignal1 = crossover(sma(close,ShortMA), sma(close,LongMA))
line1 = plot(ShortMACode, color=color.silver, title="Short MA", style=plot.style_line, linewidth = 0)
line2 = plot(LongMACode, color=color.black, title="Long MA", style=plot.style_line, linewidth = 0)
fill(line1, line2, color = ShortMACode>LongMACode ? color.green : color.red)
plotshape(BUYSignal1, style=shape.triangleup,location=location.abovebar, color=color.green, size=size.small)
//End of "Green" executed code

// "Yellow" Code would be something like and if "Yellow" is selected at DropDownInput only these rows of code would execute
ShortMA = input(defval=20)
LongMA = input(defval=40)
ShortMACode = sma(close,ShortMA)
LongMACode = sma(close,LongMA)
BUYSignal1 = crossover(sma(close,ShortMA), sma(close,LongMA))
line1 = plot(ShortMACode, color=color.silver, title="Short MA", style=plot.style_line, linewidth = 0)
line2 = plot(LongMACode, color=color.black, title="Long MA", style=plot.style_line, linewidth = 0)
fill(line1, line2, color = ShortMACode>LongMACode ? color.green : color.red)
plotshape(BUYSignal1, style=shape.triangleup,location=location.abovebar, color=color.green, size=size.small)
//End of "Yellow" executed code

// "Red" Code would be something like and if "Red" is selected at DropDownInput only these rows of code would execute
ShortMA = input(defval=30)
LongMA = input(defval=60)
ShortMACode = sma(close,ShortMA)
LongMACode = sma(close,LongMA)
BUYSignal1 = crossover(sma(close,ShortMA), sma(close,LongMA))
line1 = plot(ShortMACode, color=color.silver, title="Short MA", style=plot.style_line, linewidth = 0)
line2 = plot(LongMACode, color=color.black, title="Long MA", style=plot.style_line, linewidth = 0)
fill(line1, line2, color = ShortMACode>LongMACode ? color.green : color.red)
plotshape(BUYSignal1, style=shape.triangleup,location=location.abovebar, color=color.green, size=size.small)
//End of "Red" executed code
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
//@version=4
study("Example Code", overlay = true, shorttitle = "ExampleCode")

// ————— Options for inputs
DD0 = "Green", DD1 = "Yellow", DD2 = "Red"

var string  DropDownInput   = input(title="Select Input", defval=DD0, options=[DD0, DD1, DD2]) 
var int     ShortMAGreen    = input(defval=15)
var int     LongMAGreen     = input(defval=30)
var int     ShortMAYellow   = input(defval=20)
var int     LongMAYellow    = input(defval=40)
var int     ShortMARed      = input(defval=30)
var int     LongMARed       = input(defval=60)
var int     ShortMA         = na
var int     LongMA          = na
var float   ShortMACode     = na
var float   LongMACode      = na
var bool    BUYSignal1      = na

var bool    selectedGreen   = DropDownInput == DD0
var bool    selectedYellow  = DropDownInput == DD1
var bool    selectedRed     = DropDownInput == DD2

if selectedGreen
    ShortMA := ShortMAGreen
    LongMA  := LongMAGreen
else if selectedYellow
    ShortMA := ShortMAYellow
    LongMA  := LongMAYellow
else if selectedRed
    ShortMA := ShortMARed
    LongMA  := LongMARed

ShortMACode := sma(close, ShortMA)
LongMACode  := sma(close, LongMA)
BUYSignal1  := crossover(ShortMACode, LongMACode)

line1 = plot(ShortMACode,   color=color.silver, title="Short MA",   style=plot.style_line, linewidth = 0)
line2 = plot(LongMACode,    color=color.black,  title="Long MA",    style=plot.style_line, linewidth = 0)
fill(line1, line2, ShortMACode>LongMACode ? color.green : color.red)
plotshape(BUYSignal1, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.abovebar, color=color.green, size=size.small)
```

Comment: Thank you Bjorn! I'll test it out :)